# How are multi-term products involving differential operators calculated?

Tags: derivatives, operator-theory

How are multi-term products involving differential operators calculated?

Such as:

$$\bigg( \frac{1}{\epsilon^2} \frac{d^2}{d \xi^2} + \frac{2}{\epsilon} \frac{d^2}{d \xi d x_0} + \frac{d^2}{d x_0^2} \bigg)(y_0 + \epsilon y_1 + ...)$$

as given in:

http://www.naturalspublishing.com/files/published/m3183f1twe241h.pdf p. 1121 (or p. 3 in pdf).

Do they follow the same rules as in abstract algebra?

So the above would be like:

$$(a+b+c)(d+e+...)$$

$$=ad+ae+bd+be+cd+ce+...$$

However, since in the case of divergence:

[image]

Then I'm not sure if the algebra way applies here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply distribute the terms, and make sure to note that the terms don’t commute, (ie. $AB \neq BA$).

For example:

$$(\dfrac{d}{dx} + \dfrac{d}{dy})(f(x) + g(y)) = (\dfrac{d}{dx} + \dfrac{d}{dy})f(x)+ (\dfrac{d}{dx} + \dfrac{d}{dy})g(y)$$

Or in the example you give:
$$\bigg( \frac{1}{\epsilon^2} \frac{d^2}{d \xi^2} + \frac{2}{\epsilon} \frac{d^2}{d \xi d x_0} + \frac{d^2}{d x_0^2} \bigg)(y_0 + \epsilon y_1 + ...) = \bigg( \frac{1}{\epsilon^2} \frac{d^2}{d \xi^2} + \frac{2}{\epsilon} \frac{d^2}{d \xi d x_0} + \frac{d^2}{d x_0^2} \bigg)y_{0} + \bigg( \frac{1}{\epsilon^2} \frac{d^2}{d \xi^2} + \frac{2}{\epsilon} \frac{d^2}{d \xi d x_0} + \frac{d^2}{d x_0^2} \bigg)\epsilon y_{1} + ...$$

Differential Operators over a ring a generally non-commutative.

What you wrote on the bottom on the question is correct.

Comment: What do you mean by "distribute"?

Comment: @mavavilj I edited my answer to illustrate what I meant.